# Regex prevent selecting characters from previous match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My title probably doesn't explain exactly what I mean. Take the following string:

```
POWERSTART9^{{2|3}}POWERENDx{{3^EXSTARTxEXEND}}=POWERSTART27^{{1|4}}POWEREND
```

What I want to do here is isolate the parts that are like this:

```
{{2|3}} or {{1|4}}
```

The following expression works to an extent, it selects the first one {{2|3}} with no issue:

```
\{\{(.*?)\|(.*?)\}\}
```

The problem is, it's not just selecting the first if {{2|3}} and the second of {{1|4}} because after the first one we have {{3^EXSTARTxEXEND}} so it's taking the starting point from {{3 and going right until the end of the second part I want |4}}

Here it is highlighted on RegExr:

[image]

I've never been great with regex and can't work out how to stop it doing that. Any ideas? I basically want it to only match the exact pattern and not something that contains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\{\{((?:(?!{{).)*?)\|(.*?)}}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xHDZ7G/1).

If there can be no `{`  and `}` inside the `{{...}}` substrings, you may use a simpler `\{\{([^{}|]*)\|([^{}]*)}}` expression (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xHDZ7G/2)).

**Details**

- `\{\{`  - a `{{` substring
- `((?:(?!{{).)*?)` - Capturing group 1: any char (`.`), as few as possible (`*?`), that does not start a `{{` char sequence ([tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970))

  - `[^{}|]*` - any 0 or more chars other than `{`, `}` and `|`
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `(.*?)`  - Capturing group 2: any 0 or more chars, as few as possible

  - `[^{}]*` - any 0 or more chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}}` - a `}}` substring.

Comment: Will this work for say 10 of them in the string or only 2?

Comment: Wow great. I need to read your comment a bit more and check against regex docs because I'm not fully following it, although it does work, thanks :)

Comment: @GlenElkins If you only have digits there, inside expected matches, you may even use `\{\{(\d+)\|(\d+)}}`, see https://regex101.com/r/xHDZ7G/4. It all depends on the actual requirements, the first regex is the most generic one.

Comment: The generic one is what I need thanks for your help, I will familiarise myself with he regex parts I don't know .

Answer (score 0):

Try this `\{\{([^\^|]*)\|([^\^|]*)\}\}`

https://regex101.com/r/bLF8Oq/1